# Creating a matrix with the smallest arrays of some matrixs in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have some different matrices with equal size, for example, say 5 different `N` by `N` matrices `A1`, `A2`, `A3`, `A4` and `A5`. I want to create an N by N matrix `B` such that `B(i, j)` is the smallest element among `A1(i, j)`, `A2(i, j)`, `A3(i, j)`, `A4(i, j)` and `A5(i, j)`.

Since `N` is a big number, more efficient code is preferred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the most pretty but `B = min(min(min(min(A1,A2),A3),A4),A5);` should work.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative,

```
A = cat(3, A1, A2, A3, A4, A5);   % store equal-size 2d arrays in 3d array
B = min(A, [], 3);                % take minimum in 3rd dimension
```

Comment: This is probably the more flexible solution.